# libcurl multi vs easy dns resolving behaviour

Tags: libcurl

I'm facing a strange issue with our new c++ wrapper over libcurl 7.33 (compiled with enable-ares, RHEL5.4). The performance is good(in msecs) when I hit http://posttestserver.com/post.php with easy interface but with multi interface dns resolving takes more time for the same url. If the libcurl callback timer timeout is used instead of our own timer logic, the request takes 2 minutes to complete. Timeout suggestion from libcurl increases like 4000, 150000..This does not happen if IP is used.

Comment: the version we use is 7.33 ..sorry for the typo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to a timeout bug present in 7.33.0. There's a newer libcurl version out that you could use to see if it the bug remains or not.

It would also help if you would provide a smallish example source code here that shows how you do this so that we can see that the code is correct from your end. Or tell us if you can use one of the existing libcurl examples on the curl site to repeat the problem.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the inputs. I'll try compiling one of the examples(hiperfifo). Also we'll try with the latest libcurl. we use libevent 1.4 which I missed to specify in the question.

Comment: I could reproduce the issue with hiperfifo example. Logs can be found here - http://pastebin.com/0tP8AV1t . libcurl timer callback timeout increases 1, 5000, 145020, 150020, -1

Comment: Use the curl-library mailing list for help to debug libcurl.

Comment: The issue was reproducible only with libcurl-v7.33 yesterday.I could compile the latest version 7.34 version today and both the hiperfifo example and our code works great. Thanks a lot Daniel.

Comment: Daniel, Should we still have our own timer logic or is it safe to use libcurl timer callback timeout with v7.34?

Comment: with the multi_socket API you really should use the CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION

Comment: Thanks Daniel. There was another issue which might be useful for others. libcurlv7.34 was triggering a crash(https://github.com/nmathewson/Libevent/commit/90539fff317d2a56b6baba52c483521314b0be57) in libeventv1.4. I had to upgrade to libevent2 to get things working. Though libevent2 is backward compatible, older (libevent1.4) methods seem to hang. libcurlv7.34 works fine with libevent2 methods.